# GARCH diagnostics via standardized residuals: interpreting my findings

Tags: python, data-visualization, interpretation, garch, diagnostic

I have fit a GARCH(1,) model in Python, assuming the residuals are $t$ distributed. I am checking the standardized residuals. ARCH and Ljung-Box tests don't reject the null hypothesis. However, I am having trouble understanding the behavior of the graphs.

The first graph displays the distribution of standardized residuals. As you can see it is not normally distributed.

[image]

The second one is the QQ plot.

[image]

The last one is a scatter plot of standardized residuals versus estimated volatility.

[image]

How do I interpret these graphs of standardized residuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "As you can see it is not normally distributed." + "I assumed that the residual of the GARCH are t distributed." = What problem do you see in that? I do not see any.
2. For the second plot, what reference distribution did you use? You should have used Student's $t$ distribution. If you did, you see it is not a great match at the left tail. You probably need an asymmetric distribution (skewed Student's $t$? Johnson's $S_U$?) to fix that. But actually it is easier to just study the probability integral transform of the standardized residuals. For a statistically adequate model, it should be Uniform[0,1] regardless of what distribution you have assumed for the standardized innovations.
3. I am not sure the third plot is all that informative. I am not used to seeing it as part of GARCH diagnostics.

Comment: thank you so much for your replies!!

Comment: @Mattia, you are welcome!